# Include file with name phonegap.js or coredova.js, While building app in build.phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing an app where including js and css files locally, like

`< script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.1.0.js" >< /script >
    < script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js" >< /script >
    < script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js" >< /script >`

After generating app by build.phonegap I found that device functions are not working like

'addEventListener'

I have Googled it and found suggestion that phonegap JS file should be without version ie. It should be included as phonegap.js

I have done suggested modifications and generated build, But not got success

So, Did it necessary to have phonegap js file name as phonegap.js (without verstion details)

or name should be coredova.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/introduction_getting_started.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Build),

> Once you've included the necessary assets, remove the phonegap.js
>   (cordova.js) as Build will automatically inject it during compile
>   time.

Basically, you don't need to include the phonegap.js because during the build process, it will automatically include it.